# PopUp not closing from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with closing a pop window. My problem is unique in kind if I click Logout from the parent, it closes all the windows, but when I log out from a child, then I am logging out from Parent, so it does not close the other child windows that are open.

When I am logging out from a child and then I am logging out from a parent, I checked in console and it is not going inside the `if` block.

I am opening all the pop-ups like this -

```
function openpop1() {
    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    userName = getURLParameters('userName');
    userId = getURLParameters('userId');
    lvalue = getURLParameters('lValue');
    lver = getURLParameters('lVer');
    window.name = "parent";
    var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen 
    var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
    var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...
                   + ",location=no"      //URL field
                   + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...
                   + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.
                   + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.
                   + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.
                   + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.
                   + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.
                   + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788
                   + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               
                   + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.
                   + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.
                   + "";  
     awin = window.open(aUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId
            + "&userId=" + userId + "&lValue=" + lvalue + "&lVer=" + lver,'_blank',strWinProp);
}
function openpop2() {
    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    userName = getURLParameters('userName');
    userId = getURLParameters('userId');
    lvalue = getURLParameters('lValue');
    lver = getURLParameters('lVer');
    window.name = "parent";
    var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen 
    var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
    var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...
                   + ",location=no"      //URL field
                   + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...
                   + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.
                   + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.
                   + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.
                   + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.
                   + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.
                   + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788
                   + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               
                   + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.
                   + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.
                   + "";  
     bwin = window.open(bUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId + "&userId="
            + userId + "&lValue=" + lvalue + "&lVer=" + lver,'_blank',strWinProp);
}
```

And while log out I am calling

```
function onLogout() {
    if (awin && !awin.closed) {
        awin.close();
    }
    if (bwin && !bwin.closed) {
        bwin.close();
    }       

    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    var rcvReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    rcvReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rcvReq.readyState == 4 || rcvReq.readyState == 0) {
            var data = rcvReq.status;
        }
    }
    rcvReq.open("GET", logoutUrl +sessionId, true);
    rcvReq.send(null);
    window.location = loginPageUrl;
}
```

Now my problem is why is it not going inside the `if` block when I am logging out from the child and then the parent. I checked this by adding a breakpoint to these lines.

```
    if (awin && !awin.closed) {
        awin.close();
    }
    if (bwin && !bwin.closed) {
        bwin.close();
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea. Please help me on this. I am not getting why it is not satisyfying the `if` condition.

Comment: Could you please provide a example of what you have so far, so we can see what's happening?

Comment: can you suggest me how?

Comment: use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I created file here but the problem is I am not able to reproduce my issue...I think because here there is no session id so it is not  giving any problem...anyway my sample link is http://plnkr.co/edit/TwUXeWV8w4LLELusP7kT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This code will only execute if awin and bwin have a valid reference to the popups.

```
if (awin && !awin.closed) {
    awin.close();
}
if (bwin && !bwin.closed) {
    bwin.close();
}
```

Try this test, after you call `awin = window.open(` write down the value for the `awin` variable and when closing the popup recheck that the `awin` value is still the same.

Comment: I checked by using breakpoints in console it is exactly the same.